# TypeError when writing to logfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, typeerror

I've set up a logger using the code below:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='application.log', mode='a+')
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Whenever I attempt to write to the log, using the below code:

```
logger.info("Application Started")
```

I get the following Traceback:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 985, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Call stack:
  File "/home/<user>/Code/<app_name>/src/<app_name>.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/<user>/Code/<app_name>/src/<app_name>.py", line 42, in main
    logger.info("Application Started")
Message: 'Application Started'
Arguments: ()
```

I'm aware that given the exception above, you would expect the file to have been opened in binary mode, except it's not, I'm only opening using "a+" mode.

**Update**
I've tried adding encoding='utf-8' to the filehandler, along with mode='a+t' and removing the named parameter filename as per the suggestions in the comments below to no avail.

Comment: I think you should use `logger.info('Application Started')` and not `logging.info('Application Started')`.

Comment: @toti08, you are indeed correct, but despite updating the code I still get the same error.

Comment: What about `mode='a+t'`?

Comment: @CristiFati, still the same unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try other values for that arg, or other args (`encoding="utf-8"`)? Also don't specify `filename=` (*keyword* arg). Anyway I can't reproduce this behavior (*Python 3.5* on *Win*)

Comment: @CristiFati, I've tried encoding="utf-8" too to no avail. Removing the filename=  doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error with the code given, however I _did_ get the error if I set the mode to 'ab+'. Have you tried deleting or moving the existing application.log out of the way?

Comment: @AlexForbes, this is why I'm so confused. I've definitely not specified the mode to be 'b'. I'm wondering if something else in the project is interfering somehow.

I've deleted the existing log file and the error still occurs.

Comment: I agree that it must be something else in the project. I'd be looking for any code that sets up or modifies the root logger.

Comment: @AlexForbes, just as I replied I found another implementation of logging within the project. Previous maintainer hid it pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a logger was being set up elsewhere in the project that uses io.BytesIO() as the stream handler. This resulted in the logger expecting bytes for one logger, and str for another. Removing the other logging implementation solved the problem.

Comment: The clue, which we all missed, was in the stack trace: `stream.write(msg)`. Clearly not writing to file! https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L941-L986